# Banshee is ignoring id3 tags?

Tags: sync, banshee, id3, easytag

I spent a lot of time cleaning up my id3 tags with [EasyTag](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) but I don't see that cleanup reflected in Banshee. If I quit EasyTag and re-open it, my work is reflected there. If I open an album and run `id3 -l` at the command line, I see my work reflected there, too (ie. the tags are right) but I'm still seeing those files listed in Banshee as "Unknown Artist" / "Unknown Album" -- no amount of `Rescan Music Library` has any affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I am using Puddletag to update the id3 tags but doesn't seem that the changes are reflected in Banshee's library even after forcing a "Rescan Music Library".

The only way I've found to make Banshee update the tags is by explicitly removing the files from the library and adding them back: right click on "Music" in the left toolbar under "Libraries", select "Import Media to Library" and select the folder where the files whose id3 tag you've updated are.

Comment: +1 This is correct. Banshee will 'Rescan' your library for new files, not metadata. It saves the tag data in it's database in `home/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db`. You could also delete this file and let Banshee rebuild it, but you lose all your playlists & preferences, etc. Best to just remove and re-add files after editing tags.

Comment: Removing banshee.db seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using PuddleTag and had success when I removed all ID3 tags, exited and restarted Puddletag and re-tagged the files.  Then importing them into Banshee showed that the problem was resolved.